# Getting appendices to be titled 'Appendix X: name' in toc and text using memoir

Tags: memoir

I'm trying to write a large paper for school and am using the memoir class.  I need to have the appendices titled as 'Appendix A: MyFirstAppendix'.  Right now, they show up as 'A: MyFirstAppendix'.  Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[openany,letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{memoir}

\chapterstyle{tandh}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
I want this to say `1 Lorem ipsum'

\appendix
\chapter{MyFirstAppendix}
I want this to say `Appendix A: MyFirstAppendix'
\chapter{MySecondAppendix}
I want this to say `Appendix A: MySecondAppendix'

\end{document}
```

I determined that I can add this command:

```
\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}
```

to write `Appendix ' before the letters of appendices in the TOC.  I can't figure out how to make it work in the text of the document though.  I feel like I might be able to write a new chapterstyle to do what I want and replace tandh?  I don't really know how to do that though, so I'm hoping I'm overthinking it.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) use a different chapter style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chapter style being used does not add a prefix to the chapter number. Thus of course, no Appendix is added. You'll need a different chapter style or use two chapter styles

```
\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{tandhapp}{%
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{1\onelineskip}%
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{2\onelineskip \@plus .1\onelineskip
                            \@minus 0.167\onelineskip}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \@chapapp~\thechapter:\space}%
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}%
%%%  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\chapnumfont\raggedright}}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\chapnumfont\memRTLraggedright}}

\makeatother
```

activated as

```
\appendix
\chapterstyle{tandhapp}
```

Extra info: `\@chapapp` is a magic macro that is `\chaptername` unless `\appendix` is active, then it resolves to `\appendixname`